# How to access sub element's attached behavior?

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to write an aurelia attached behavior for https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable that allows to reorder items in a list using html 5 drag and drop similar to the one they have in place for AngularJS. So far drag and drop of the html elements is working perfectly with the following template code

```
<template>
  <require from="./sortable"></require>
  <section>
    <h2>${title}</h2>
    <ul sortable>
      <li repeat.for="item of items">${item.title}</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>
```

and attached behavior

```
import {Behavior} from 'aurelia-framework';
import Sortable from 'rubaxa-sortable';

export class SortableAttachedBehavior {
  static metadata() {
    return Behavior
      .attachedBehavior('sortable');
  }

  static inject() {
    return [Element];
  }

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  bind(viewModel) {
    this.sortable = Sortable.create(this.element);
  }

  unbind() {
    this.sortable.destroy();
    this.sortable = null;
  }
}
```

As the next step in addition to reorder the html elements I also want to reorder the data items in the model. I can get the required events about dnd from the sortable instance I have. My problem is now to obtain a reference to the items.

As I only want to do this if a repeat.for behavior is present on the sub element I think the best way would be to get access to its Repeat instance and update the contents of its items property. But how do I check for the existence of this attached behavior and how do I obtain the Repeat instance?

Or is there a better approach to get access to the items (besides specifying them as a property of my sortable behavior once again)?

Cheers, Tilmann

Comment: I know this is an old post, but wondering if you're still hitting issues here?   You should be able to use a custom attribute here vs. attached behavior.   Assuming that you do that, the `viewModel` that's passed to bind is the parent, so you should be able to save that e.g. `this.$parent = viewModel`, and then `this.$parent.items` should be defined.

Comment: please mark as answered, or close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plugins for that already
for example https://github.com/buttonwoodcx/bcx-aurelia-reorderable-repeat

You can check out how it is implemented by looking @ the source (-: